# How to detect and remove unnecessary xmlns:<something> attributes in PHP DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Say I have a source document like this:

```
<element>
  <subelement xmlns:someprefix="mynamespace"/>
</element>
```

The `xmlns:someprefix` is obviously not needed here and doesn't do anything since that prefix is not being used in that element (or in my case, anywhere in the document).

In PHP, after I've loaded this into a DOM tree with DOMDocument->loadXML(), I'd like to be able to detect that such a namespace declaration exists, and remove it.

I know that I can read it with `hasAttribute()` and even remove it with `removeAttributeNS()` (strangely) but only if I know its prefix.  It doesn't appear in `DOMNode->attributes` at all, as the thing I'm trying to find is not considered an attribute.  I cannot see any way of detecting that it is there without knowing the prefix, other than serialising it back to an XML string and running a regex or something.

How can I do it?  Any way to query which namespaces (ie xmlns:something) have been declared in an element?

Comment: I guess one way to answer this is "don't worry about it".  Looks like these attributes don't affect DTD validation at all (document's still valid), they just waste unnecessary bytes and make the document look ugly.  So I could perfectly well just ignore the issue for now... still, it'd be nice if there was a solution for this.

Comment: that's really the only answer. Just ignore it. At some point in the future, you may add a child `<someprefix:someelement/>`, at which point, you'll want the namespace back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to detect:

```
<?php
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadXML('
<element>
  <subelement xmlns:someprefix="http://mynamespace/asd">
  </subelement>
</element>');
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($d);
$namespaces = $sxe->getDocNamespaces(true);
$x = new DOMXpath($d);
foreach($namespaces as $prefix => $url){
        $count = $x->evaluate("count(//*[namespace-uri()='".$url."' or @*[namespace-uri()='".$url."']])");
        echo $prefix.' ( '.$url.' ): used '.$count.' times'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

How to remove: pfff, about your only option that I know of is to use `xml_parse_into_struct()` (as this is not libxml2 reliant afaik), and looping through the resulting array with `XML Writer` functions, skipping namespace declarations which are not used. Not a fun passtime, so I'll leave the implementation up to you. Another option *could* be XSL according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981028/bypassing-namespaces-while-copying-an-xml-with-xslt), but I doubt it is of much use. My best effort seems to succeed, but moves 'top-level'/rootnode namespaces to children, resulting in even more clutter.

**edit**: this seems to work:

Given XML (added some namespace clutter):

```
<element xmlns:yetanotherprefix="http://mynamespace/yet">
  <subelement
        xmlns:someprefix="http://mynamespace/foo"
        xmlns:otherprefix="http://mynamespace/bar"
        foo="bar"
        yetanotherprefix:bax="foz">
        <otherprefix:bar>
                <yetanotherprefix:element/>
                <otherprefix:element/>
        </otherprefix:bar>
        <otherprefix:bar>
                <yetanotherprefix:element/>
                <otherprefix:element/>
        </otherprefix:bar>
        <yetanotherprefix:baz/>
  </subelement>
```

With xsl (namespaces & `not()` clause based on previous $used array, so you'll still need that afaik.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:yetanotherprefix="http://mynamespace/yet"
    xmlns:otherprefix="http://mynamespace/bar"> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='someprefix')]"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element xmlns:yetanotherprefix="http://mynamespace/yet">
  <subelement xmlns:otherprefix="http://mynamespace/bar" foo="bar" yetanotherprefix:bax="foz">
        <otherprefix:bar>
                <yetanotherprefix:element/>
                <otherprefix:element/>
        </otherprefix:bar>
        <otherprefix:bar>
                <yetanotherprefix:element/>
                <otherprefix:element/>
        </otherprefix:bar>
        <yetanotherprefix:baz/>
  </subelement>
</element>
```

Comment: You can remove these namespaces and their associated prefixes using removeAttributeNS() - see the comment from "primaryspace" on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattributens.php - it's really weird that it's possible but it works!  The only part that I was stuck on was detecting the prefix and namespace URL which existed in the first place - but your first example appears to solve this - thanks!