# Save a copy of external xml file without using xml namespace

Tags: php, javascript, xml, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect and remove unnecessary xmlns:<something> attributes in PHP DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810569/how-to-detect-and-remove-unnecessary-xmlnssomething-attributes-in-php-dom)

Perhaps you can help me with this problem. I have a XML file on an external server which I can only reach trough a https connection in my browser (the external XML is provided by an external firm). I want to save it as a new XML file on the webserver of my website but without certain elements, like the namespace declaration (because I want to process the CML further with XSL in dreamweaver).
How can I do this in PHP or Javascript? I'm not really a programmer but I know Javascript and PHP enough to do simple things.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the file with curl or file_get_contents (I prefer curl) and then process the result with preg_match_all, or any other replace option that you like to remove the namespace references, the definition and any other part that you need.

Bye

Comment: thank everybody...i've found a solution with your tips

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick. Just replace data to suit your needs.

```
$feed = file_get_contents("http://www.sitepoint.com/recent.rdf");
$feed = preg_replace("/<.*(xmlns *= *[\"'].[^\"']*[\"']).[^>]*>/i", "", $feed); // This removes ALL default namespaces.
$xml_feed = simplexml_load_string($feed);
```